# Building Named parameter support for Java

Tags: java, named-parameters

I was thinking of building a tool through which we can have [Named Parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter) in Java 8+. I am looking for approaches on how to move forward with this. Here's what I have thought of so far,

1. Writing a compiler plugin which rewrites the method arranging and matching the parameters. In case it is not able to do so, it will throw a well defined exception. Caveat is I would also need to write extensions for IDEs so it does not show as a compile error in IDE.
2. Writing a buildscript which does the same as above, but does it pre-compilation. We still have the same problem as above and on top, I would have to write for multiple build systems.
3. Use AOP and use `@Named` annotations to specify names. IntelliJ and Eclipse both support aop compilers so IDE support should not be an issue. However this adds an extra overhead of adding AOP framework as a dependency.

There might also be some way to leverage Kotlin over here, but I am still exploring that.Looking forward to some ideas that I am completely unaware of as well as feasibility of what I have suggested.

I am not sure if opening a JEP would help as a [proposal in 2015](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2015-April/017157.html) was shot down.

FYI, I am not looking for answers/comments like why not switch to Kotlin. The point of this question is to know how feasible it is to implement this in Java, without changing the JDK itself.

Comment: How would you handle parameters that weren't passed?  There's a reason why named parameters and default parameters are features that tend to go together.  (Personally, I jumped ship from Java to Kotlin.  It's a very easy jump, and I'd recommend everyone take a look at it.)

Comment: That's not the point, I know you can switch to Kotlin, the point of this question is how do you get it in Java ? 
How would you handle parameters that weren't passed?  Fail compilation.